# Ubuntu freezes only mouse cursor movable and keyboard solutions don't work

Tags: 14.04, kernel, freeze

Solutions like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScreen</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and its variants all don't work, it seems my keyboard is frozen. And could anyone spot what caused system failing? I attach my `syslog` here:

```
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078396] INFO: task kworker/5:3:3442 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078399]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078399] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078400] kworker/5:3     D 0000000000000000     0  3442      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078425] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078427]  ffff8803cc9ebb58 0000000000000046 ffff880340ca3b00 ffff8800b6de8ec0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078428]  0000000100367e4c ffff8803cc9ec000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078430]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cc9ebb78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078431] Call Trace:
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078435]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078437]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078439]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078441]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078443]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078451]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078453]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078455]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078457]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078458]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078468]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078470]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078472]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078474]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078475]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078476]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078478]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078479]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078482] INFO: task kworker/5:1:5369 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078483]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078484] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078484] kworker/5:1     D 0000000000000000     0  5369      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078494] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078495]  ffff8803cafa3b58 0000000000000046 ffff88040a271d80 ffff8803e4e0e740
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078496]  000000010036629c ffff8803cafa4000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078497]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cafa3b78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078499] Call Trace:
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078500]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078501]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078503]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078505]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078506]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078507]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078509]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078516]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078517]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078518]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078520]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078521]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078530]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078532]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078533]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078535]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078536]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078538]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078539]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:05:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14737.078540]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890922] INFO: task kworker/5:3:3442 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890926]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890927] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890929] kworker/5:3     D 0000000000000000     0  3442      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890954] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890956]  ffff8803cc9ebb58 0000000000000046 ffff880340ca3b00 ffff8800b6de8ec0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890958]  0000000100367e4c ffff8803cc9ec000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890960]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cc9ebb78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890962] Call Trace:
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890968]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890970]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890974]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890977]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890980]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890992]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890995]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.890997]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891000]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891003]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891018]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891021]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891024]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891026]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891029]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891031]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891033]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891035]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891039] INFO: task kworker/5:1:5369 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891040]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891041] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891042] kworker/5:1     D 0000000000000000     0  5369      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891058] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891059]  ffff8803cafa3b58 0000000000000046 ffff88040a271d80 ffff8803e4e0e740
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891061]  000000010036629c ffff8803cafa4000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891063]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cafa3b78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891065] Call Trace:
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891068]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891069]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891072]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891074]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891076]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891079]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891081]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891092]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891094]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891096]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891098]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891101]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891114]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891117]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891119]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891122]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891124]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891126]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891127]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:07:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14856.891129]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703351] INFO: task kworker/5:3:3442 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703354]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703355] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703356] kworker/5:3     D 0000000000000000     0  3442      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703373] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703374]  ffff8803cc9ebb58 0000000000000046 ffff880340ca3b00 ffff8800b6de8ec0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703376]  0000000100367e4c ffff8803cc9ec000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703377]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cc9ebb78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703378] Call Trace:
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703382]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703384]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703386]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703388]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703390]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703398]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703400]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703401]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703403]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703405]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703415]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703417]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703419]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703420]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703422]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703423]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703424]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703426]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703428] INFO: task kworker/5:1:5369 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703429]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703430] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703430] kworker/5:1     D 0000000000000000     0  5369      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703440] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703441]  ffff8803cafa3b58 0000000000000046 ffff88040a271d80 ffff8803e4e0e740
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703442]  000000010036629c ffff8803cafa4000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703444]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cafa3b78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703445] Call Trace:
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703447]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703448]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703449]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703451]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703452]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703453]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703455]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703462]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703463]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703464]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703466]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703467]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703476]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703478]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703479]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703481]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703482]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703483]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703485]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:09:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [14976.703486]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:10:29 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15020.529410] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:38 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15028.756536] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:42 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15032.654447] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:43 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15033.932448] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:43 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15034.140122] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:43 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15034.315834] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:43 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15034.491560] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:44 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15034.683267] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:44 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15034.954846] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:50 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15040.705846] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:50 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15041.440683] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:10:52 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15042.622832] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515797] INFO: task kworker/5:3:3442 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515800]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515800] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515801] kworker/5:3     D 0000000000000000     0  3442      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515819] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515821]  ffff8803cc9ebb58 0000000000000046 ffff880340ca3b00 ffff8800b6de8ec0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515822]  0000000100367e4c ffff8803cc9ec000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515824]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cc9ebb78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515825] Call Trace:
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515829]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515831]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515834]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515836]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515838]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515846]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515848]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515849]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515851]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515853]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515863]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515866]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515867]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515869]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515871]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515872]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515874]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515876]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515879] INFO: task kworker/5:1:5369 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515881]       Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515882] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515883] kworker/5:1     D 0000000000000000     0  5369      2 0x00000000
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515893] Workqueue: events intel_mmio_flip_work_func [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515894]  ffff8803cafa3b58 0000000000000046 ffff88040a271d80 ffff8803e4e0e740
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515895]  000000010036629c ffff8803cafa4000 0000000000000000 7fffffffffffffff
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515897]  ffff88040a340000 ffff88040a341f28 ffff8803cafa3b78 ffffffff817b8b57
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515898] Call Trace:
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515900]  [<ffffffff817b8b57>] schedule+0x37/0x80
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515901]  [<ffffffff817bb511>] schedule_timeout+0x201/0x2a0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515903]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515904]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515906]  [<ffffffff8101d7f9>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515907]  [<ffffffff810e711e>] ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515909]  [<ffffffff817b81c6>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa6/0x120
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515916]  [<ffffffffc02c1401>] __i915_wait_request+0x3f1/0x530 [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515917]  [<ffffffff810b7970>] ? prepare_to_wait_event+0xf0/0xf0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515918]  [<ffffffff810a9066>] ? set_next_entity+0xa6/0x4c0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515919]  [<ffffffff817ae9da>] ? queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xb/0xf
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515921]  [<ffffffff8101f352>] ? __switch_to_xtra+0x142/0x180
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515929]  [<ffffffffc0302800>] intel_mmio_flip_work_func+0x40/0x3a0 [i915]
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515931]  [<ffffffff8108fb0e>] process_one_work+0x14e/0x3d0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515933]  [<ffffffff810901ba>] worker_thread+0x11a/0x470
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515934]  [<ffffffff810900a0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x310/0x310
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515936]  [<ffffffff81095732>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515937]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515938]  [<ffffffff817bc7df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 15 14:11:46 mi-OptiPlex-7040 kernel: [15096.515939]  [<ffffffff81095660>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
```

**Machine information**

DELL OptiPlex 7040

Ubuntu 14.04

kernel version 4.2.0-27-generic

Comment: dose terminal opens when you press `alt +ctrl +t` ?

Comment: also provide more information about your machine and os version

Comment: @SmitPatil nope, it seems the keyboard just breaks

Comment: @SmitPatil It is DELL OptiPlex 7040 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, kernel version 4.2.0-27-generic.

Comment: Try to boot from  windows or live usb ...etc.and see if there your keyboard works . if yes then you need to install drives in Ubuntu.

Comment: also can you click from your mouse??

Comment: Could you try to boot another kernel version? @SmitPatil This looks like a kernel problem (similar to kernel panic) rather than a keyboard or mouse related one.

Comment: @SmitPatil mouse only moves, but clicking doesn't do anything

Comment: @Melebius what is the purpose for booting to another version?

Comment: @MeadowMuffins ,by booting from another version can determine that it is hardware problem or software problem like kernel,drivers..etc.

Comment: try adding code `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu lucid main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

then type command  

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`     source :-https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1638864

Comment: @SmitPatil OP is not using Lucid. You should update your instruction.