# Laptop keyboard not working after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 16.10

Last night I've upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, and after that I cannot type anything. It's very strange and annoying because I didn't find anything like this: touchpad is working normally, event the wifi button is working, but nothing else.

Here's some info:
Laptop: HP 250 g4
Ubuntu version: 16.10
Kernel version: 4.8.0-51

Comment: do you same promblem like https://askubuntu.com/questions/915269/ubuntu-freezes-only-mouse-cursor-movable-and-keyboard-solutions-dont-work?noredirect=1#comment1442380_915269

Comment: nothing, fresh install ubuntu 17, will never upgrade again

Comment: This question lacks hardware information and relates to an upgrade to EOL version. If you're still having the problem, please update it with relevant info about your hardware, Ubuntu version, kernel version etc as much as possible. Meanwhile, I'm voting to close this question as it seems abandoned and not answerable with the current information.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is a long-term-support release; 16.10 (2016.October) was not and its support ended a year ago. Why upgrade to 16.10??  16.10's upgrade path was to 17.04 (also EOL) then 17.10 then 18.04. Do you mean something other than an old-release?  (kernel 4.8 is EOL, unsupported with no meltdown, no spectre or any post-EOL update).

Answer (score 1):

I have a flex 2 laptop and I had the same issue.

I installed Windows 8.1, which worked fine, then I updated the BIOS from official software and installed Ubuntu again, and it's working fine now.

Comment: @K7AAY this person doesn't have the same problem - they say they *had* the same problem, and they solved it by updating the BIOS. That might not be the answer to this particular question, since OP hasn't given hardware information, but it is not a "me too" comment.